# Gap above a navbar in mobile view with viewport

Tags: html, css

I started diving into html/css this evening and stumbled upon a roadblock. I am trying to make a navbar for my GitHub page and it displays just fine on desktop view. The navbar is to be fixed on desktop view, however on mobile view I want to keep in on the top of the page.

This is how it displays when `width` is less than `600px`.
[image]

I want to remove the gap above the navbar but can't figure out how.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; padding-top: 40px;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #daf2ea
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
    height: 40px;
    background: #333;
    color: #eee;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #777;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 26px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000;
    float: left;
}

.navbar a {color:white;}

.navbar a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}

.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

.navbar li {float: left;}

.navbar li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .navbar {
        position: static;
        top: auto;
        width: auto;
        padding-bottom: 14px;
    }

    .navbar h1 {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }

    .navbar li {float: none;}

    .navbar li a:hover {
        background-color: #1384c1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Lukasz Salitra - Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="navbar">
          <h1><a href="index.html">Lukasz Salitra</a></h1>
          <ul>
              <li>
                  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="about.html">About</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `padding-top: 40px;` line from `html` selector.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```